# Add the factors of a number

Tags: java, addition, factors

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = 0;
  int g = 0;
  int term = 0;
  int temp = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  int factor = 1;
  System.out.print("Input N:");

  n = x.nextInt();
  g = n;
  if (n <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer");
    System.exit(0);
  }

  if (n > 0) {
    System.out.print("The factors are:");

    while (factor < n) {
      if (n % factor == 0) {
        System.out.print(factor + ",");
      }
      factor++;
    }
  }
}
```

If I input number 8, the factors are 1,2, and 4. What I am trying to achieve is to add the factors of 8 which are 1,2 and 4, which would result in 7.

Comment: What's the question? :)

Comment: Looks like badly done homework to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=0;int g=0; int term=0;int temp=0;
    int sum=0; int factor=1;
    System.out.print("Input N:");

    n=x.nextInt();
    g=n;
    int number = 0;
    if (n<=0)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (n>0)
    {
        System.out.print("The factors are:");

        while (factor<n)
        {
            if (n%factor==0)
            {
                System.out.println(factor+",");
                number+=factor;
            }
            factor++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum = "+number);
}
}
```

Comment: You are able to give accepted flag.. u don't have right to give up vote... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.*


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int num = kb.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        int x = 1;
        for(x = 1; x <= num; x++){
            if (num % x == 0){
                sum = sum + x;
            } 
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: The best answers provide some explanation to any code that's given so it's helpful to any future users that may want to understand it or get an overview of the most crucial parts.